# Filter dates in a dictionary - python

Tags: python, date, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
> { "Country1": {"time": [1/22/20, 1/23/20...], "cases":[0,10,20,...]},
> "Country2": {"time": [1/22/20, 1/23/20...], "cases":[0,10,20,...]},
> .... }
```

I want to drop the dates higher than a given date and their respective cases. I've tried with this, but it fails because of IndexError: list index out of range. How would yo do it?

```
for i in (range(len(Country_Region))):
    for j in (range(len(Countries_Dict[i][Country_Region[i]]['time']))):
        if datetime.strptime(Countries_Dict[i][Country_Region[i]]['time'][j], '%m/%d/%y')  > datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%y'):
            Countries_Dict[i][Country_Region[i]]['time'].pop(j)
            Countries_Dict[i][Country_Region[i]]['cases'].pop(j)
```

Dates are in string format, and the desired output is the same dictionary as before without the dates higher than a given date and their respective cases.

Comment: are the dates in `string` format?

Comment: Those times will become floats, for example `1/22/20` -> `0.0022727272727272726`. They're supposed to be strings, aren't they?

Comment: Related: [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/4518341)

Comment: It would help if you provided all the details, meaning some complete, valid example input, and the desired output, sort of like a [mre]. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Yes, the dates are in string format

Answer (score 0):

Your `IndexError` is likely a fault of inconsistent data, with `time` and `cases` having different lengths.

You can use `zip` to bunch them together clipping at length of the smaller list.

```py
data = {
    'Country1': {
        'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/25/20'],
        'cases': [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]   # Inconsistent data
    },
    'Country2': {
        'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/25/20'],
        'cases': [0, 10, 20, 30]
    }
}

threshold_date = '1/23/20'


def parse_date(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y')


for country, country_data in data.items():
    pre_threshold = [
        (time, case)
        for time, case in zip(country_data['time'], country_data['cases'])
        if parse_date(time) <= parse_date(threshold_date)
    ]
    country_data['time'] = [t for t, c in pre_threshold]
    country_data['cases'] = [c for t, c in pre_threshold]
```

This will result in,

```
{'Country1': {'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20'], 'cases': [0, 10]},
 'Country2': {'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20'], 'cases': [0, 10]}}
```

Notice that the first list had 4 vs 5 entries in `time` and `cases` but it didn't matter.

This is creating a new list, the efficiency of this code can be improved, but I've kept it so for the readability. You can choose to do so based on your need.